# No provider for NavController! Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm Using `Ionic3` for my university project , I had added setting parts of my `app.html` and trying to link `(click)="home()"` but it's not working for me.

I got following error

> Error: No provider for NavController!
>       at injectionError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1527:90)
>       at noProviderError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1565:12)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3007:19)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3046:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:2978:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:2847:21)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:9847:25)
>       at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10935:16)
>       at resolveDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11438:45)
>       at createClass (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11302:32)

app.html

```
<!--------------------------------------Main Navigation--------------------------->

<ion-menu id="myMenu" [content]="content" side="right" persistent="true" [class]="selectedTheme">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-grid>

        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6>
            <div text-left style="" class="app-listname">
              Project</div>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col  (click)="home()">
            <div class="tether-setting" style="text-align: right;font-size: 2rem; color:#a57958;">
              <ion-icon ios="ios-settings-outline" md="md-settings"></ion-icon>
            </div>

          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <div class="tether-logout" style="font-size: 2rem; color:#a57958; text-indent: 0rem;  text-align: right;">
              <ion-icon ios="ios-log-out" md="md-log-out"></ion-icon>
            </div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>

    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <div class="ion-tm">
      <ion-list>
        <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" [class.activeHighlight]="checkActive(p)" (click)="openPage(p)">
          <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" item-left></ion-icon>{{p.title}}</button>

      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false" [class]="selectedTheme"></ion-nav>
<!--------------------------------------Main Navigation--------------------------->
```

**app.component.ts**

```
   import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Nav, Platform,NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import {HomePage} from '../pages/home/home';

import {SettingsPage} from "../pages/settings/settings";
import {HelpPage} from "../pages/help/help";

import {UserloginslidePage} from "../pages/userloginslide/userloginslide";
import {SettingsProvider} from "../providers/settings/settings";
import {ModalPage} from "../pages/modal/modal";
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any = UserloginPage;
  selectedTheme: String;  //Themeoption
  activepage: any;
  pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, icon: string }>;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,private settings: SettingsProvider,private navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.settings.getActiveTheme().subscribe(val => this.selectedTheme = val);  //Themeoption

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });


    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });


    this.pages = [

      {title: 'Dashboard', component: HomePage, icon: "ios-home-outline"},

      {title: 'Settings', component: SettingsPage, icon: "ios-settings-outline"},
      {title: 'Help', component: HelpPage, icon: "ios-help-circle-outline"},
      {title: '  User loginslide ', component:UserloginslidePage, icon: "ios-contact-outline"},


    ];

    this.activepage = this.pages[0];
  }


  //Themeoption
  openPage(page) {


    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
    this.activepage = page;

  }
  checkActive(page) {
    return page == this.activepage;
  }

  home(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, why do you try to import NavController? You have   `@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;` you can use it.

You *must* remove **NavController** from injecting in your constructor

Replace your line

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,private settings: SettingsProvider,private navCtrl: NavController) {
```

with

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,private settings: SettingsProvider) {
```

**Then** replace the line

```
 this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
```

with

```
 this.nav.push(HomePage);
```

Comment: try this solution as well

Comment: nav is not defined. I adding your code in app.component.ts (ionic 3)

Comment: Navigation is not available when using `nav` and user can not go back!

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari when are you calling nav? in constructor on on ng init?

Comment: @HamidAraghi without code I wont be able to help... This is solution  I am using so if its null then probably you are doing something different

Comment: Hello @volodymyr-bilyachat! This solution works and i can navigate, but how to pass params? I'm in the `app.component.ts` and I can't use `NavController`. The unique way which works to push a page is with `this.nav.push`, but params not working.

Comment: @volodymyr-bilyachat I solved the params. I'm use: `this.nav.push(page, paramObj)` and works!

Comment: I see a solution, but I don't see an explanation. Why does the error happens?

Comment: @MMalke because when you inject it in constructor is not yet ready I assume. I believe this issue is fixed in ionic 4

Answer (score 32):

Try using `getActiveNav()`

Like this,

```
import {App} from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public app: App){}

login() { 
    this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot(Home); 
}
```

Comment: You should state that they need to remove NavController from constructor

Comment: is this your updated code? there is no getActiveNav()

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat why? it will not throw any error even if you have it imported

Comment: @Gowtham i think it will throw an error if you try to inject it. Yes if you just import its ok, but if you inject it it will fail.

Comment: (getActiveNav) is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Use getActiveNavs instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this problem in ionic 3 by following code.

```
import {App} from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public app: App){}

login() { 
    this.app.getActiveNav().push(XxxPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Ionic v3 docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component):

> You can't inject NavController because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the root component so they aren't available to be injected.

You will need to remove the NavController from the constructor, as it cannot be injected, and trying to do so will result in the error you're facing.

Instead you should have an `<ion-nav>` component on your app template, and get its instance on the AppComponent's code-behind by using the @ViewChild directive.